VS Code R Extension: Inability to View Objects in Global Environment and Display Graphs within VS Code Window after Recent Update
I use R on VS Code and I've never had any issues whatsoever. Recently, I restarted the extension and since then, I haven't been able to see objects in the global environment anymore. When I try to open a plot or an object, it shows up in an R window instead of VS Code as it did before.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension, restarting VS Code, and searching for someone else who has had the same issue, but nothing worked. Could you help me restore it? I noticed that the developers made an update three days ago (2.8.3), I'm not sure if it's related, but it seems likely since it coincides with when I started experiencing problems. However, I think something went wrong at least in my case because I haven't seen any updates mentioning these changes, which are clearly worse compared to the previous functionalities.

It sounds like it's not seeing your terminal is an R session. In your settings.json do you have "r.sessionWatcher": true?
